# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I'm getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

at SnakeBox.neighbor(SnakeBox.java:150)

at SnakeBox.findSnake(SnakeBox.java:86)

at pg6a.main(pg6a.java:28)
```

The class being used is:

```
/** This class can be used to manipulate 2D boxes of "snakes" for pg6.
 */
   import java.util.*;
   import java.io.*; 

 public class SnakeBox {

// instance variables
  private char[][] box;
  private int rows, columns;
  private int snakeCount;
  private int startRow, startCol;
  private int endRow, endCol;
    private boolean finish;
    private int x, y;
    private String toDisplay;

/** Create and initialize a SnakeBox by reading a file.
    @param filename the external name of a plain text file
*/
  public SnakeBox(String filename) throws IOException{
     Scanner filescan = new Scanner(new FileReader(filename));
     rows = filescan.nextInt();
        columns = filescan.nextInt();
        snakeCount = filescan.nextInt();
        filescan.nextLine();
        box = new char[rows][columns];
     for (int i=0; i < rows; i++) {
        String line = filescan.nextLine();
        for (int j=0; j < columns; j++) {
           char character = line.charAt(j);
           box[i][j] = character;
        }
     }  
  }

   /** Create a new snakebox of a given size and snake count
@param rows the height of the box
@param cols the number of columns
@param snakes how many snakes are in the box
    */
  public SnakeBox(int rows, int cols, int snakes) {
     this.rows = rows;
     this.columns = cols;
     this.snakeCount = snakes;

  }

/** Display the box on the screen.
 */
  public void display() {
     String toDisplay = ""; 
     for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
           toDisplay += box[row][column];
        }
        toDisplay += '\n';
     }  
        System.out.print(toDisplay);

  }

/** Find the next snake, skinning to change it from S to .
 */
  public void findSnake() {
    // check to make sure there are still snakes to skin
      if (finish = true) {              
    int row, col, nb;
    // find an S to search from
      outerloop:
      for (int k=0; k < rows; k++) {
          for (int l=0; l < columns; l++) {
          if (box[k][l] == 'S') {
          startRow = k;
          startCol = l;
          endRow = k;
          endRow = l;
          break outerloop;
          } 
      }
      }
    // set your initial S position to both start and end

    // search from end, updating it as you go
     do {
        nb = neighbor(endRow, endCol);
        switch (nb) {
           case 1: endRow--; endCol--; 
              break;
           case 2: endRow--; 
              break;
           case 3: endRow--; endCol++; 
              break;
           case 4: endCol--; 
              break;
           case 5: endCol++; 
              break;
           case 6: endCol--; endRow++; 
              break;
           case 7: endRow++; 
              break;
           case 8: endRow++; endCol++; 
              break;
        }
     } while (nb != 0);

    // search from start, updating it as you go
    do {
        nb = neighbor(startRow, startCol);
        switch (nb) {
           case 1: startRow--; startCol--; 
              break;
           case 2: startRow--; 
              break;
           case 3: startRow--; startCol++; 
              break;
           case 4: startCol--; 
              break;
           case 5: startCol++; 
              break;
           case 6: startCol--; startRow++; 
              break;
           case 7: startRow++; 
              break;
           case 8: startRow++; startCol++; 
              break;
        }
     } while (nb != 0);

    // update snake count
      snakeCount = snakeCount - 1;        
      //display start/end points of the snake, then display it
  }   
/** Change a position from S to . and find a neighboring S if one exists.
    @param x the row number of the position to change
    @param y the column number of the position to change
    @return 0 if no S neighbor was found, or a number from this grid 
    indicating the position of the found neighbor
           1 2 3
           4 S 5
           6 7 8
*/
  }
    private int neighbor(int x, int y) {
       box[x][y] = '.';

        if (box[x--][y--] == 'S') 
        return 1;

        if (box[x--][y] == 'S') 
        return 2;

        if (box[x--][y++] == 'S')
        return 3;

        if (box[x][y--] == 'S') 
        return 4;

        if (box[x][y++] == 'S') 
        return 5;

        if (box[x++][y--] == 'S') 
        return 6;

        if (box[x++][y] == 'S') 
        return 7;

        if (box[x++][y++] == 'S') 
        return 8;

        else        
     return 0;     

    }

/** Display the endpoints of the snake most recently skinned.
 */
  public void printEnds() {
  System.out.print("(" + x + "," + y + ")");
  }

/** Find out how many full snakes are in the box.
    @return the snake count
*/
  public int getCount() {
    return snakeCount;      
  }

/** Check whether all the snakes have been skinned, based on the snake count.
    @return true if done, false otherwise
*/
  public boolean finished() {
    if (snakeCount == 0) {
    finish = true;
    }
    else {
    finish = false;
    }      
    return finish;
  }

   }
```

Also, the driver program (pg6) is:

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;

 public class pg6a {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.println("Please enter the name of the file where your snake box resides, and we will try our very best to eliminate all the snakes in your snake box!");
     String filename;
     filename = keyboard.nextLine();
     SnakeBox snakes = new SnakeBox(filename);
     snakes.display();

     while (snakes.finished() == false) {
        snakes.findSnake();
        snakes.printEnds();
        snakes.display();
        System.out.print(snakes.getCount());
     }                      
  }
}
```

Comment: The error involves the lines:

nb = neighbor(endRow, endCol);

if (box[x--][y] == 'S') 

return 2;

And from the driver program:

snakes.findSnake();

Answer (score 2):

Its because of those `if` statements in the `neighbor()`.

`if (box[x--][y--] == 'S')` - whether this evaluates to `true or false`, this will decrement your `x` & `y`.

Similarly, all your `if` statements, will keep `decrementing` or `incrementing` `x & y`. That's why at a point, the value of either `x` or `y` or both go below `0`, giving an `index` of `-1` in the array. And hence the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You can fix it by using `x-1` & `y+1` in the `if` statements, instead of the `increment/decrement` operators.

This line `SnakeBox.neighbor(SnakeBox.java:150)` says the error exists in `neighbor` method and just by looking at the `if` statements in the `neighbor()` method, tells you what could have possibly gone wrong.

Comment: It would be better if you add how you found the error in code (hint: reading the stacktrace maybe?)

Comment: I used x-1 and y+1 before I used the increment/decrement operators, but I got the same error message.

Comment: I updated the neighbor method by using x-1 and y-1 but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner - That being said, you must also make sure, that you handle the cases, where `x & y` are `0`. If you don't handle that, no matter whether you use `x-- or x-1`, you'll get that exception, because it'll give the result `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
box[x--][y--]
```

You are not checking the boundary conditions of the box before attempting to access them. Also, using x-- changes the value of x at each stage. Use them absolutely - `x-1` etc.

Your other variables suffer from the same problem `case 2: endRow--;`

Comment: How do I check the boundary conditions of the box before attempting to access them?

Comment: if (y < 0 || y >= box[x].length ) That will tell you if you are accessing an array index out of range. Use similar code for checking the boundaries of x.